# Location tracking in background with Universal Windows 10 app

Tags: c#, geolocation, windows-phone, win-universal-app, windows-10

I am trying to "refresh" an old Windows Phone 8.0 app that needs location tracking in the background. It's not possible to "upgrade" it to Windows Phone 8.1 (as the background location tracking does not work).

I need to fetch the position let's say every minute. If I migrate the app to Windows 10 UAP will the location tracking in the background work?

Comment: I plan to write a simple application and check if it works. I thought somebody did that already so I can save some time ;) Will get back with my results.

Comment: Did it work for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The UAP means of background tracking is handled by an **ExtendedExecutionSession** (at least in the March 2015 Tech Preview):

```
private ExtendedExecutionSession session;

private async void StartLocationExtensionSession()
{
   session = new ExtendedExecutionSession();
   session.Description = "Location Tracker";
   session.Reason = ExtendedExecutionReason.LocationTracking;
   session.Revoked += ExtendedExecutionSession_Revoked;
   var result = await session.RequestExtensionAsync();
   if (result == ExtendedExecutionResult.Denied)
   {
       //TODO: handle denied
   }
}
```

This example comes from http://www.sharpgis.net/post/2015/03/29/Using-Windows-10s-Extended-Execution.

Comment: Do we need to add  this in Background Tasks? Because when I used this in my project. I get location details when app is in foreground as well as background(app is minimized) but it doesn't detect when user kills the app.